# Adding Headers to Firefox HTTP Request without Using PlugIns

Tags: rest, firefox, browser, http-headers, httprequest

I have Firefox version 52.1. I cannot udpate to newer version, nor can I add plugins that people ordinarily install to address these issues.

I am calling some rest services that require communicating that these are POST request plus a couple of other things ordinarily communicated through hearder information.

What options do I have for adding these specific header requirements to my Firefox request assuming I cannot add plugins or upgrade to a newer version of the browser? Thank you.

Comment: ok, I have figured out how to modify indivudual requests using the basic developer tools available to the browser. So I guess I should respond and close this (even though I am still not sure how to specify the specific header items I need).

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Ok, so simply by opening the very basic developer tools (i.e. press F12), then executing the request (which will fail because it is missing header info), then selecting the network tab in the tool followed by the All within the Network frame, it shows the failure info. Then I can select the default method value (GET) in the table of the attempted request, it will open a frame of the right of the tool. This frame has a header tab whose frame allows you to modify the header by clicking the Edit and Resend button. Click that button and then add the additional needed header params. then click the resend button.

Comment: I think a lot of the middle part of this answer could be replaced with just saying "Right-click the request and click 'Edit and Resend'"

Comment: Might be obvious, once your resent request comes back as 200 click it in the Network frame and then the Response tab to see the (possibly truncated) response.

Comment: @valid How can I see that response in webpage instead of in response tab?

Comment: `Referer` and some other headers are unavailable for editing in 'Edit and Resend'.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use Postman. Especially when you're going to do this on a regular basis. I started out using just the browser like you, but it got pretty cumbersome, so I switched to Postman.
[web.postman.co](https://web.postman.co)